# Pandas: How to concatenate dataframes with different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to find the answer in the official [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), but found it more confusing than helpful. Basically I have two dataframes with overlapping, but not identical column lists:

```
df1:
   A   B
0  22  34
1  78  42

df2:
   B   C
0  76  29
1  11  67
```

I want to merge/concatenate/append them so that the result is

```
df3:
   A   B   C
0  22  34  nan
1  78  42  nan
2  nan 76  29
3  nan 11  67
```

Should be fairly simple, but I've tried several intuitive approaches and always got errors. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need merge with parameter how = outer

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer')

    A       B   C
0   22.0    34  NaN
1   78.0    42  NaN
2   NaN     76  29.0
3   NaN     11  67.0
```

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to concatenate the dataframes you can use.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

output:

```
      A   B     C
0  22.0  34   NaN
1  78.0  42   NaN
0   NaN  76  11.0
1   NaN  11  67.0
```

Then you can reset_index to recreate a simple incrementing index.

```
pd.concat([df,df2]).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output:

```
      A   B     C
0  22.0  34   NaN
1  78.0  42   NaN
2   NaN  76  11.0
3   NaN  11  67.0
```

Comment: This solution is working perfectly well, the downvoter should explain

Comment: It seems that this does indeed work as well, although I thought I had already tried this. Can someone explain what the difference to the outer merge is?

Comment: Merge acts like a SQL join, where you are looking for overlapping rows and getting back a single row for each overlapping row, where outer returns all records from both dataframe, but if there is overlapping rows base join condtion, then it will produce one row.  pd.concat, simply stacks the two dataframes on top of each other.  There is no joining ie... no looking for overlapping rows.

Comment: this doesn't work; it will keep the column names with actual rows

Answer (score 3):

Both @vaishali and @scott-boston solution work. I prefer the merge function as it allows more flexibility on your result with the how parameter. However concat can achieve better performance if few columns are involved

To optimize @scott-boston answer, you can also use the internal concat parameter `ignore_index` that automatically resizes the index without calling another function. The code would be like :

```py
pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
```

Output

```py
      A   B     C
0  22.0  34   NaN
1  78.0  42   NaN
2   NaN  76  11.0
3   NaN  11  67.0
```

Python (version 3.8.5) | pandas(version 1.1.3)