# parquet: Dataset files with differing columns

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Using pyarrow.
I have a Parquet Dataset composed of multiple parquet files. If the columns differ between the files then i get a "ValueError: Schema in  was different".

Is there a way to avoid this?
Meaning i'd like to have a Dataset composed of files which each contain different columns.

I guess this could be done by pyarrow by filling in the values of the missing columns as na if the columns are not there in a particular component file of the Dataset.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder why this question has 2 downvotes, while it's quite clear and definitely non-obvious issue to solve with pyarrow. Did you manage to solve your problem? I am trying to solve similar issue - accessing hdfs and reading data from parquet files, however some files have a different schema than others.

Comment: It's by design, all files in a Dataset must have the same schema. There are efficient ways to read the schema of file so you can avoid blowing up.

Comment: It happens quite often that the schema evolves over time, as one day there might be a decision to add a column to the dataset, without changing the past parquet files. Ideally i would like to get in such a case missing values in the historical data when i try to read both old and new parquet files at once. But i wasn't able to figure it out yet. I suppose pyarrow might add this functionality to 'non-legacy' dataset in the future... or do you know how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

Loads the files with separate dataframes such as df1 and df2, merge those dataframes by referencing [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252759/pandas-how-to-concatenate-dataframes-with-different-columns) article.

In the article, you may find two ways to merge, one is

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer')
```

and the other one with the pandas package as follows:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: that's not quite what i was meaning, i'm after partitioning by column. Will update my question to reflect this.